# toggleClass() is not working properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am running code where I need to toggle one class but it is not working. I want that on click of one element, `emailmodels`, the class `pinkthumb` gets added and on clicking again it should be removed.

When I call `addclass()` then it is adding the class `pinkthumb`, but when I call `toggleClass()` it is not working.

```js
$(".emailmodels").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("pinkthumb");
});
```

```css
.pinkthumb {
  background: #f14d76 !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
@foreach($modeldetail->photos as $photo)
  <li class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 xyz allphotos photocat_{{$photo->photocategory_id}} ">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$photo->id}}">
    <a href="#myphotoModal" class="thumbnail modelphotos makedisplaypicturediv emailmodels">
      <img src="{{$photo->thumb}}" alt="{{$photo->filename}}">
      <input type="checkbox" class="photoids dispnone" value="{{$photo->id}}">
    </a>
    <a class="group1 colorboxcat_{{$photo->photocategory_id}} dispnone" href="{{$photo->px640}}" title="{{$modeldetail->user->name}}">Grouped Photo 1</a>
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$modeldetail->id}}">
    <input type="radio" value="{{$photo->id}}" {{($photo->featured=='1')?'checked':null}} name="model_pic_featured" class="model_pic_featured"/><span>Make display picture</span>
  </li>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work fine in isolation: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nmjr7Lue/. Check the console for errors

Comment: I think your html is invalid - you shouldn't have inputs in anchors, you may want to change it for a label instead

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Is `.emailmodels` generated dynamically by JS or is it in the resulting HTML from your scrip? If the former, you may want to use `.on()` instead of `.click()`.